# Is count a "requirement" in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have done some research but I haven't found a straight answer to my question.

**Is doing a count before a loop is the good way to do it ?**

Is that better to do :

```
if(count(array) > 0){
    foreach(array as entry){

    }
}
```

OR

```
foreach(array as entry){

}
```

From my point of view, the count is an extra step because if the array is empty, we won't loop.

What do you think about it ?

Comment: I don't use the extract check in any language that supports "enumerating empty sequences". If array does not represent something that can be enumerated then yes - a check *is* required. I write code to avoid this case, where practical.

Comment: I would include either the count or if(!empty(array)), but its not required, I would only require it if you had some other kind of iterable object

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try some simple test;

**Test 1**

```
$array = "string";
foreach ( $array as $entry ) {
}
```

Output

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**Test 2**

```
$array = "string";
if (count($array) > 0) {
    foreach ( $array as $entry ) {
    }
}
```

Output

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**Test 3**

```
$array = "string";
if (is_array($array) || $array instanceof Traversable) {
    foreach ( $array as $entry ) {
    }
}
```

Output

```
 No error
```

You don't have to validate all the time .. but when you are not sure of the value ... you should check if its valid before you loop.

Comment: I prefer the way you do it with the test number 3. We first look if it's an array and/or a Traversable variable/object call it whatever you want. Thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

if there is nothing in the array, the foreach loop will loop 0 times. Checking the count ahead would be un-necessary. Depending on what the possible values for $array are, you would probably be better to test for is_array() because a foreach will throw an error if $array is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with `count()` it's similar to doing `is_array()`. Foreach will give you a error if it is not an array.

A better way, imo, is going with `if(!empty($array)){`